# Python script working properly on my ASP.Net MVC5 web application BUT not working after I publish my web app on my local server

Tags: python, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, publish

I have created a function in my C# MVC5 web app that calls a python script to create a folder on a network drive.

When I test my application, the script runs perfectly after the solution is built, however, it does not work when I publish my application to my local server.

Below is the code I am using:

```
public void CreateFolderAndFiles(int operation, string fileName, string fileName_confirmed)
{
     string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
     var cmd = "-u " + "create_folders_and_files.py";
     var process = new Process
     {
          StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
          {
          FileName = @"python.exe",
          Arguments = cmd + ' ' + operation.ToString() + ' ' + fileName + ' ' + fileName_confirmed,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          RedirectStandardError = true,
          CreateNoWindow = true
          },
          EnableRaisingEvents = true
     };

            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
}
```

I tried changing the paths of the python and the file (in both absolute and relative forms), but nothing worked.

The IIS server is on the same machine I am using when I build my solution, and the files paths did not change.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? have you configured the FastCGI handler in iis? please post more details information about your issue.

Comment: No error messages received. For the FastCGI, can you please give me a document I can follow to install it?

Comment: FastCGI is an interface that works at the request level. IIS receives incoming connections and forwards each request to a WSGI app running in one or more persistent Python processes. [Configure the FastCGI handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022).